# replace controls in <li>

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do i replace the controls in a list item using server side code.  I need to replace this

```
    <li>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnPreRender="btn_PreRender" CommandName="Uploader"
            TabIndex="2">Upload</asp:LinkButton>
        or <a target="_blank" href="../PersonalInfo/MailingAddress.htm">Mail</a> the form.
    </li>
```

with

```
    <li>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="hplnkViewDocument" runat="server" Text="View Document" SkinID="lnkBtnBlue"></asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have both controls in the `li`, then only show/hide the one you want, using the `Visible` property.

Comment: I would have two li in a ol. Hide the desired one accordingly sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can put a pannel or some server side control that works as a container. Then you can add or remove from their controls collection whatever controls you like.

Lets say a pannel that you want to add a button to, just to give you an idea:

```
Button button = new Button ();
//Set properties accordingly
Pannel1.Controls.Add(button);
```

Also, Controls is a property of Control, so you will find it in any class that inherits Control. Even the page inherits from a class that inherits from control.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read about ["Page.FindControl Method (String)"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx).

There is some sample as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
 Page.Controls.Remove(btnUpload);
```

and then create the `hplnkViewDocument` as new LinkButton control

```
  Page.Controls.Add(hplnkViewDocument);
```

Answer (score 0):

;-)

If you wanted to be super lazy you could just wrap the either of them in a span with a given class and then add some css to the page head (assuming it runs at server) that has display:none; visiblity: hidden; for the class that shouldn't show

HTML:

```
<li>
  <span class="one">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnPreRender="btn_PreRender" CommandName="Uploader" TabIndex="2">Upload</asp:LinkButton>
  or <a target="_blank" href="../PersonalInfo/MailingAddress.htm">Mail</a> the form.
  </span>
  <span class="two">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="hplnkViewDocument" runat="server" Text="View Document" SkinID="lnkBtnBlue"></asp:LinkButton>
  </span>
</li>
```

Make sure to add either:

```
.one {display:none; visiblity: hidden;}
```

...or

```
.two {display:none; visiblity: hidden;}
```

...based on your runtime needs